# ERROR Error: Cannot insert a destroyed View in a ViewContainer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have designed a page generator by configuration app and it works fine and generate components and render them on the page as good as it should.

But when i try to render a new page by new configuration, i get this error `ERROR Error: Cannot insert a destroyed View in a ViewContainer!` right when the generator service try to render the first component on the page after cleaning the page.

The pages configuration arrives from `pageConfigService` at `ngOnInit` in `NemoContainerComponent` and error appears when `pageGenerator` try to render the `WidgetContainerComponent`.

** UPDATE **

Page will be generate after changing the rout, all of the routes base component is the `NemoContainerComponent` and when route changes, the `NemoContainerComponent` destroyed and created again.

** UPDATE **

This is `NemoContainerComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nemo-container',
    templateUrl: './nemo-container.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class NemoContainerComponent {

    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

    @ViewChild(ChildReferenceDirective) childReference: ChildReferenceDirective;

    constructor(
        private pageGenerator: PageGeneratorService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private routeService: RouteService,
        private router: Router,
        private storeEngine: StoreEngineService,
        private pageConfigService: PageConfigService
    ) {
        this.subscription.add(route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            this.routeService.setRouteService = params;
        }));
        let activeRoute = router.url.split('/').join(' ');
        document.body.className += ' ' + activeRoute;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageGenerator.containerRef = this.childReference.viewReference;

        this.subscription.add(this.pageConfigService
            .get(this.route.data['value'].page)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.pageGenerator.renderNewPageByConfigurationFile(data.json)
            }));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

`WidgetContainerComponent` is here:

```
@Widget({
    typeName: 'widget-container',
    displayName: '',
    type: 'parent',
    settings: []
})
@Component({
    selector: 'widget-container',
    templateUrl: "widget-container.component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class WidgetContainerComponent {

    @ViewChild(ChildReferenceDirective, { read: ViewContainerRef }) childRef;

    get childReference(): ViewContainerRef {
        return this.childRef;
    }

    private data: ObjectInterface = {};
    set widgetData(value: ObjectInterface) {
        for (let item in value) {
            this.data[item] = value[item];
        }
    }
    get widgetData(): ObjectInterface {
        return this.data;
    }

    public id: string = '';
}
```

** UPDATE **

angular pack version: 4.4.6

** UPDATE **

thanks in advance for your helps :)